# Find a value in corresponding cell to 5th recurrence of particular value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Here: Please suggest a formula to find the corresponding cell value where "22" has occurred 5th time. For example in below case, the corresponding value is "SA"    . Thanks in advance

```
22  A
33  B
44  C
55  D
232 E
32  AA
12  AA
21  FF
21  GG
22  A
121 DDA
22  AS
12  DS
122 RE
44  SDS
22  a
232 DS
22  SA
```

Comment: I don't have time to dig deep but this might be a place to start: http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010567_Finding_the_Nth_Occurrence_of_a_Character.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your values are in A2:B19 use the following:

```
=INDEX(B2:B19,SMALL(IF(A2:A19=22,ROW(A2:A19),""),5)-1)
```

Enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The `IF` function will return an array with the row numbers where the value in column A equals 22. `SMALL` will return the 5th value of that array. Subtract one because data starts on the second row. `INDEX` will get the intended value on column B.